# How do I update a function using array values

Tags: python, quandl

I am trying to make a stock screen in python using the Quandl libraries. The python package requires the format `"dataset"/"stockticker"_"indicator"` to retrieve the data. So `example/AAPL_mktcap` would give the market cap for Apple. I have already created a text file with all the stock tickers. My question is how do I best go about switching from `example/AAPL_mktcap` to `example/AAPL_pricetoearnings` or from `example/AAPL_mktcap` to `example/MSFT_mktcap` if say `if pricetoearnings <= 30`is true or false.

Comment: tell us what you did. use this to ask questions: [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also read [the good question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear what you're asking, however it seems like string formatting is what you want to do. You could do something like'

```
result = '{dataset}/{stockticker}_{indicator}'.format(
    dataset='example',
    stockticker='AAPL',
    indicator='mktcap'
)
```

Or geared specifically towards what you say in the title (using an "array"), you could do this (where params is a [dataset, stockticker, indicator] iterable)

```
result = '{}/{}_{}'.format(*params)
```

or

```
result = '%s/%s_%s' % params
```